# change span tag on hover of button

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a span tag within a button. I just want the span text to change on hover from white to dark when I hover the button. The only way right now it will work is if I put the hover on the span tag itself and then the mouse pointer has to be exactly on the text within the button. If not the whole button is white on hover.

```
a.sf-button.transparent-dark span {

}

a.sf-button.transparent-dark span:hover {

}

a.sf-button.transparent-dark {
    color: #FFF;!important;
    background-color: #12225b;
}

a.sf-button.transparent-dark:hover {
    color: #666;!important;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border: 1px solid rgba(34,34,34,.2);
}

a.sf-button, a.sf-button:hover, #footer a.sf-button:hover {
    color: #666;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border: 1px solid rgba(34,34,34,.2);
}
`
```

I can not change the way the button is setup because its part of a theme.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="sf-button large transparent-dark stroke-to-fill " href="https://www.domain.com" target="_self"><span class="text">button text</span></a>
```

I actually went ahead and setup a fiddle for this. And it actually works on the fiddle. So perhaps this means something is interfering with it. But I can not determine what would be.

http://jsfiddle.net/robmcmon/4ZWUX/

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Without that, there isn't much we can do to help

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Something in the index wordpesss theme just keeps overwritten my child css style for that element.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
.test-button:hover .test-span {
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

This should change the spans appearance when the button is changed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DbpgW/