# Why :hover css is not trigged in button tag? (with firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, hover

I have an class CSS with `:hover` effect.

I want scope it in  but it's does't working :

```css
.test
{
 background-color: blue;   
}

.test:hover
{
   background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<button><span class="test">test</span></button>
<span class="test">test</span>
```

EDIT : other example: http://jsfiddle.net/zge5nzq8/2/

So why and how can I do?

EDIT : it's working with Chrome but not FF.

Comment: When I hover on button or on span, it's background color is changed to red.

Comment: It's working as supposed : on :hover on .test element, the background becomes red. You putted class test on span, not on button element.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: place the hover on the button !?! `button:hover { background:red }`

Comment: in which browser? it works for me in Chrome - both go red

Comment: with chrome it's working, but not with FF.

Comment: @Danield no... look comment to Mahesh Thumar answer plz

Comment: I wanted to check something and copied your code to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zge5nzq8/ and on FF everything works for me... so it looks like snippet runner problem here

Comment: @Kania the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zge5nzq8/1/ just let the class on span in button

Comment: @Matrix - true, did you check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092133/change-span-tag-on-hover-of-button ? I think this solution should work for you

Comment: @Kania but it's not a button in this exemple. I change my own exemple like this : http://jsfiddle.net/zge5nzq8/2/ (to be understand class on span can't go on button)

Comment: and this is a bug already created for FF -> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003

Comment: @Kania so the solution is just be patient to the next version? :s

Comment: the solution for you is probably change a little sprite, to have a little more space around icon you need, or use font-icon: check this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zge5nzq8/3/

Comment: For your css hover add "button:hover span.test" to the hover class.  That should work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2zLfsm02/ (answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in firefox:  (fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2zLfsm02/)

```
.test
{
 background-color: blue;   
}

.test:hover, button:hover span.test
{
   background-color: red;   
}
```

and html the same:

```
<button><span class="test">test</span></button>
<span class="test">test</span>
```

**You may want be more specific with the styling in my example (button:hover span.test) and give that button a class.

Comment: yes, I find this solution by myself ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this?

```css
.test
{
 background-color: blue;   
}

.test:hover
{
   background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<button class="test"><span >test</span></button>
<span class="test">test</span>
```

Comment: sure not, i'm not stupid^^ I have a sprite with a background-image on span in <button>, I can't put it on button. I use bg-color exemple just to watch hover is not trigged.

Comment: This must be a browser specific issue. I can see the red background color for both the cases in Q & A !

Comment: yes, it's not working with FF only...

Comment: I am using FF30 and it works fine for me!

Comment: I'm using FF 34.0 on ubuntu and it's not for me.

Comment: same thing on window.